# Run-time error '28' on my utilities module (Access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, recursion, vba, runtime-error, utilities

For the life of me I can't find out the reason why code stopped compiling, it has a runtime error 28 - Out of Stack Space

It used to compile fine and it stopped with new update to Windows 10.  Not even sure if that is related.  Could it be just too many utilities in one module?

It is mostly just supposed to have all the message boxes, set the date to a fiscal year format and export the tables to a backup excel spreadsheet.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Global CurrentUserID As Long
Global CurrentUsername As String
Global CurrentUserPrivileges As UserPrivilegesEnum

Const FMonthStart = 10
Const FDayStart = 1
Const FYearOffset = -1

Public cmd As New Commands

Global lHeader As Long
Global lHeaderText As Long
Global lBodyText As Long
Global lDetail As Long

Public Enum StringIDEnum
    AppTitle = 1
    DebuggingMessage = 2
    ErrorHasOccured = 3
    ELookupError = 4
    SaveChangesPrompt = 5
    ConfirmParaLNDeletion = 6
    NoRecordsChanged = 7
    CannotDeleteAssignedParaln = 8

End Enum

Public Enum UserPrivilegesEnum
    ADMIN = 1
    User = 2
    Inactivated = 3
End Enum

Function MsgBoxYesNo(StringID As StringIDEnum, Optional ByVal strInsert As String) As Boolean
    MsgBoxYesNo = vbYes = MsgBoxID(StringID, vbYesNo, strInsert)
End Function

Sub MsgBoxOKOnly(StringID As StringIDEnum, Optional ByVal strInsert As String)
    MsgBoxID StringID, vbOKOnly, strInsert
End Sub

Function MsgBoxYesNoCancel(StringID As StringIDEnum, Optional ByVal strInsert As String)
    MsgBoxYesNoCancel = MsgBoxID(StringID, vbYesNoCancel, strInsert)
End Function

Function MsgBoxOKCancel(StringID As StringIDEnum, Optional ByVal strInsert As String)
    MsgBoxOKCancel = MsgBoxID(StringID, vbOKCancel, strInsert)
End Function

Function MsgBoxID(StringID As StringIDEnum, Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle, Optional ByVal strInsert As String) As VbMsgBoxResult
    MsgBoxID = MsgBox(InsertString(StringID, strInsert), Buttons, LoadString(AppTitle))
End Function

Function LoadString(StringID As StringIDEnum) As String
    LoadString = ELookup("[StringData]", "tblStrings", "[StringID]=" & StringID)

    ' Verify that the specified string was found using DLookupStringWrapper.
    ' If you hit this breakpoint, verify that the StringID exists in the Strings table.
    Debug.Assert LoadString <> ""
End Function

Function InsertString(StringID As StringIDEnum, strInsert As String) As String
    InsertString = Replace(LoadString(StringID), "|", strInsert)
End Function
Function GetFiscalYear(ByVal X As Variant)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If X < DateSerial(Year(X), FMonthStart, FDayStart) Then
        GetFiscalYear = Year(X) - FYearOffset - 1
    Else
        GetFiscalYear = Year(X) - FYearOffset
    End If
Done:
   Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "GetFisalYear() -- GetFiscalYear")
    Resume Done
End Function
Function GetMonthEnd(ByVal X As Variant)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim M As Variant
    M = DateSerial(Year(X), Month(X) + 1, 0)
    GetMonthEnd = M
Done:
   Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "GetFisalYear() -- GetMonthEnd")
    Resume Done
End Function
Public Function Proper(X)
'Capitalize first letter of every word in a field.


Dim Temp$, C$, OldC$, i As Integer

     If IsNull(X) Then

           Exit Function

     Else

           Temp$ = CStr(LCase(X))

           ' Initialize OldC$ to a single space because first
           ' letter must be capitalized but has no preceding letter.

           OldC$ = " "

            For i = 1 To Len(Temp$)
                   C$ = Mid$(Temp$, i, 1)
                   If C$ >= "a" And C$ <= "z" And (OldC$ < "a" Or OldC$ > "z") Then
                         Mid$(Temp$, i, 1) = UCase$(C$)
                   End If
                   OldC$ = C$
            Next i

            Proper = Temp$

      End If

End Function

Public Sub OpenSpecificExcelFile(sFilePath)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim sFullPath As String
    Dim sPath As String

    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

     '   Only XL 97 supports UserControl Property
    On Error Resume Next
    oXL.UserControl = True
    On Error GoTo 0


     '   Full path of excel file to open
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    '   Open it
    With oXL
        .Visible = True
        .Workbooks.Open (sFilePath)
    End With


Done:
    Set oXL = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    oXL.Visible = False
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo Done

End Sub
Public Function QueryExists(QueryName As String) As Boolean
    Dim Db As Database 'DAO Vars
    Dim QDF As DAO.QueryDef
    On Error GoTo NoQuery 'If there is no Query capture the error.
    Set Db = CurrentDb()

    'If Query is there return True

    For Each QDF In Db.QueryDefs
       If QDF.Name = QueryName Then

          QueryExists = True

          Db.Close
          Set Db = Nothing
          Exit For
       End If
    Next

    Exit Function
NoQuery:
    'If Query is not there close out and set function to false
    Db.Close
    Set Db = Nothing

    QueryExists = False
    Exit Function
End Function
Public Function CreateOrgCharts() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim varDate As Variant

    varDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Format(Time, "Long Time"), ":", ""), " AM", "AM"), " PM", "PM")
    strFilePath = "Org_Charts_" & varDate & ".xls"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "qryOrgCharts", _
        strFilePath, , "Org Charts"

    CreateOrgCharts = True

Done:
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "CreateOrgCharts() -- mdlUtilies")
    Resume Done
End Function
Public Function Backup() As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim varDate As Variant

    varDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Format(Time, "Long Time"), ":", ""), " AM", "AM"), " PM", "PM")
    strFilePath = "Toolkit_backup_files_" & varDate & ".xls"


    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tblEmerContact", _
        strFilePath, , "Emer Contact Info"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tblMovements", _
        strFilePath, , "Movements"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tblUsers", _
        strFilePath, , "User Info"

    Backup = True
Done:
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Backup() -- mdlUtilies")
    Resume Done
End Function

Public Function BackupReferenceTables() As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim varDate As Variant

    varDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Format(Time, "Long Time"), ":", ""), " AM", "AM"), " PM", "PM")
    strFilePath = "Toolkit_ReferenceTables_backup_files_" & varDate & ".xls"


    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tblPositions", _
        strFilePath, , "Positions"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tblSection", _
        strFilePath, , "Sections"

    BackupReferenceTables = True

Done:
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Backup_reference_tables() -- mdlUtilies")
    Resume Done
End Function

Function IsSelectedVar( _
        strFormName As String, _
        strListBoxName As String, _
        varValue As Variant) _
            As Boolean
    'strFormName is the name of the form
    'strListBoxName is the name of the listbox
    'varValue is the field to check against the listbox
    Dim lbo As ListBox
    Dim item As Variant
    If IsNumeric(varValue) Then
        varValue = Trim(str(varValue))
    End If
    Set lbo = Forms(strFormName)(strListBoxName)
    For Each item In lbo.ItemsSelected
        If lbo.ItemData(item) = varValue Then
            IsSelectedVar = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Have you checked whether any of [these reasons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523(v=vs.60).aspx) are applicable? If you aren't able to ascertain the line of code or function causing the error, I would suggest taking a copy of the module and systemically removing functions until the error no longer appears in order to locate the cause.

Comment: A runtime error is something very different to a compile error. What is it? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: thank you, isolating the functions right now